# electron-forge with two windows : how to render the second window? electron-react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I realized that the second electron browser window, does actually opens, but it doesn't render correctly.

In /tools/forge/forge.config.js I have two entryPoints for the two windows:

```
        entryPoints: [

        {
          // React Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
          rhmr: 'react-hot-loader/patch',
          // HTML index file template
          html: path.join(rootDir, 'src/index.html'),
          // Renderer
          js: path.join(rootDir, 'src/renderer.ts'),
          // Main Window
          name: 'main_window',
          // Preload
          preload: {
            js: path.join(rootDir, 'src/preload.ts'),
          },
        },

        {
          // React Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
          rhmr: 'react-hot-loader/patch',
          // HTML index file template
          html: path.join(rootDir, 'src/index_two.html'),
          // Renderer
          js: path.join(rootDir, 'src/renderer_two.ts'),
          // Main Window
          name: 'main_window2',
          // Preload
          preload: {
            js: path.join(rootDir, 'src/preload.ts'),
          },
        },

      ],
```

And this is the related part in main.ts :

```
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;

let mainWindow;
let mainWindow2;

const createWindow = (): void => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({

  })
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  mainWindow2 = new BrowserWindow({

  })

  // Is this correct??
  mainWindow2.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
}
```

/src/renderer.ts :

```
import './app';
```

/src/renderer_two.ts :

```
import './app_two'
```

In src/app_two/components/App_two.tsx  :

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h2 className='heading'>
            SECOND WINDOW
        </h2>
        <p>
          <button id="exchange-greetings-with-first-window" onClick={() => {
            exchangeGreetingsFunct();
          }}>Exchange Greetings with First Window</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the second window, which is the one on the right, doesn't rendere correctly:

[image]
How to correctly load the rendering for the second window?

Answer (score 8):

Hello on entryPoints in package.json file you should do some thing like this

```
"entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/foldera/view.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "foldera_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/foldera/preload.js"
              }
            },
            {
              "html": "./src/folderb/view.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "folderb_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/folderb/preload.js"
              }
            }
          ]
```

then you can use

```
FOLDERA_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY FOLDERA_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY
FOLDERB_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY FOLDERB_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY
```

I think that the variable name depends on the name of the entryPoints

Comment: "I think that the variable name depends on the name of the entryPoints" it does! it was my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

With this in main.ts :

```
ipcMain.handle("open-second-window", (IpcMainEvent, message) => {
  //mainWindow2.loadURL(path.join('file://', process.cwd(), 'index-2.html'));
  mainWindow2.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/main_window2'); // corresponding 
       to the main_window2 in /stc/tools/forge/forge.config.js : 
  mainWindow2.show();
});
```

I get the correct rendering [image]